# When running tensorboard on MacBook, this error keeps showing up: No dashboards are active for the current data set

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard

I'm running a CNN training model with tensorflow. I want to visualize accuracy of the training model with Tensorboard. I tried the following variations:

```
tensorboard --logdir=/Users/Desktop/model_folder 
tensorboard --logdir="/Users/Desktop/model_folder"
```

But every time I try to load Tensorflow in my browser, the error is: no dashboards are active for the current data set.

I saw some solutions for Windows where they specified the network drive; however, mac does not have a network drive, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Are there solutions to this error for MacBook? Or are there other ways of visualizing training model accuracy with python?

Comment: Are you creating the logs for tensorboard to read? IIRC this requires adding the tensorboard callback in the callbacks parameter of `fit`

Comment: Can you provide the complete reproducible code to help you in localizing what could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

To simply visualise you don't specifically need tensorboard and can just use `history` object that the `fit` method returns:

```
import pandas as pd

#### here you create your model ####

hist = fit(x, y)
histdf = pd.DataFrame(hist)

# Plot loss
hist_df.loc[:, ['train_loss', 'val_loss']].plot(kind='line')
# Plot accuracy
hist_df.loc[:, ['train_accuracy', 'val_accuracy']].plot(kind='line')
```

You can of course also import matplotlib and set up plots in more detail.